# Bootstrap modal doesn't work on live server

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, modal-dialog

Trigger Button:

```
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
        $name = $row['name'];
        $id = $row['id'];
        echo '<a data-target="#exampleModal" class="wpmui-field-input button wpmui-submit button-primary" data-toggle="modal" data-whatever="'.$name.'">Details</a>';
        echo $id . "<br>";
    }
```

Modal:

```
echo'
<div class="modal fade" id="exampleModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <textarea class="form-control"></textarea>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>';
```

JavaScript:

```
echo'
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.onload = function () { 
        $("#exampleModal").on("show.bs.modal", function (event) {
  var button = $(event.relatedTarget) // Button that triggered the modal
  var recipient = button.data("whatever") // Extract info from data-* attributes
  var modal = $(this)
  modal.find(".modal-title").text("New message to " + recipient)
  modal.find(".modal-body textarea").val(recipient)
})
     }
</script>';
```

Now I have all these codes above that will generate a Modal Box when clicked on that Trigger Button. This code seems to work fine in my localhost but it doesn't act the same in my server, and the values returned are `undefined`. Now, I think it might have something to do with the PHP Version, because my localhost has PHP7 and my server has PHP5. Does this mean  in PHP5 does not support value field (JavaScript is `.val()`) in the `<textarea>` tag as in `<textarea value="something">`?

Even if that's the case, what is the workaround for this problem? I tried using `.html()` and `.text()` but all it does is overwriting the value, and when you open up the modal box once again, the value will be the same for ALL modal boxes (whereas it should be different value for each recipient modal box).

Comment: I prefered writing modal in html than php as display none

Comment: I'm using a Wordpress, the XYZ PHP Code, inside the field it only accepts php parameter values, therefore I have to use the echo "<HTML>" thingy.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have'nt included necessary jquery and style files.try including bootstrap.js, jQuery.min.js 
This one might be helpful for you
www.bootply.com/mRbjbQ1JAB
Good Luck.

Comment: Of couse I did import everything beforehand. Also, everything I did in my localhost, I did also in my server, basically just copy and paste the codes (Trigger Button, Modal, Javascript), but only in that server, the values returned are undefined, on my localhost, it returned correct values for each Trigger Button.

Answer (score 0):

Use chrome developer tools or in firefox depending on your browser, click on the network tab and load the page the modal is supposed to appear, check all the files listed in the network tab of developer tools for anyone with 404 not found, that is possibly what is missing.